# what is the keywork of App_Path in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

what is the keywork of App_Path in vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2008 Framework 3.5 you can [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6whasz3x(VS.80).aspx)

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Answer (score 0):

To click the below link:

http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=148101